# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using spring-security for a desktop application, below is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd" >

<bean id='myProvider' class='MyAuthenticationProvider'/>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref='MyAuthenticationProvider' />
</security:authentication-manager>  

<bean id='authenticationHolder' class='AuthenticationHolder' />
<bean scope="request" factory-bean="authenticationHolder" factory-method="getAuthentication" >
    <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
        <security:user name="testUser" password="testPassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:user-service>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter">
                <property name="rolePrefix" value="MY_PREFIX_" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" 
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" />
```

When running I am getting this exception

```
SEVERE: Failed to load required web classes
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
```

Any help? thanks

**[EDIT]**
    forgot to add jar to project!

Comment: are you sure you are getting it when compiling? This looks to me like a runtime error

Comment: and how are you running it? On what container?

Comment: thanks it's already solved I should have added the jar file